# Display search results of UISearchController properly

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have the following scenario:

A `TableViewController` (let's call him TVC1) with a navigation bar.
In `viewDidLoad` of TVC1 I create a `UISearchController` (called searchController) and set it as search controller of the navigation item

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

Then I have a second `TableViewController` (TVC2) that should display the search results.

```
UISearchController(searchResultsController: tvc2)
```

If I now use the search bar I can see my result table but it fills the complete screen, instead of replacing the table of tvc1.
So even the search bar is not visible anymore.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Here demo project  may be help you https://github.com/paresh1994/UISearchController-in-swift-4

Comment: Thanks, but your example project doesn't use a searchResultsController.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer :) 
In TVC1 it was necessary to set

```
definesPresentationContext = true
```